# Git: cherry-pick commit, but only changes inside specific directory

Tags: git

I have a commit in different branch, which have modified multiple files in multiple directories. I would like to cherry-pick the commit, but only the changes in a specific directory and discard other changes. Being located in the directory of interest and knowing the commit-id, what is the correct command to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cherry-pick the commit without immediately committing:

```
git cherry-pick -n <sha>
```

Then remove all files from staging

```
git reset HEAD .
```

and re-add and commit only the files you want

```
git add specific_directory/
git commit
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't `git reset HEAD` do the same job (at your step 2)? By default, all files are involved, aren't they?